# Master\owner can't edit or delete tags on gitlab repository

Tags: git, permissions, gitlab

I'm trying to delete the tag with specific user by

```
    git push --delete origin deleteme
```

I'm authorized by ssh key with user that belongs to admin group and have "Owner" permissions to the repository. I'm getting the following error:

```
    remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to change existing tags on this project.
```

If I create a new user with the same permissions, I am able to delete tags successfully. I tried to revoke and grant ownership again but nothing changed. Logs say nothing. The only difference between this user and the new one is that naughty user does not use LDAP.
Tags on the project are not protected.

Has anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: Have the same issue. Maybe you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

For the majority of users this is probably not the problem, but for some users it might be helpful to notice that protecting the **creation of tags for some users** by default **disables editing and deleting of that tags for all users** as well.

> By default, protected tags are designed to:
>
> - Prevent tag creation by everybody except Maintainers
> - Prevent **anyone** from updating the tag
> - Prevent **anyone** from deleting the tag

More on that here: https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/protected_tags#overview